# How can I uncheck a child formgroup value if parent is unchecked (Angular)?

Tags: angular

I have a reactive form group with two checkboxes. How can I uncheck the support checkbox if the pacct checkbox is unchecked?

```
    this.userForm = this.fb.group({
        phone: [this.data.phoneContact.data, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4}$')]],
        paiosfg: this.fb.group({
            pacct: [this.data.pAccountId > 0],
            support: [this.data.isSupportLic]
        }),
});
```

HTML

```
...
<div formGroupName="paiosfg">
    <mat-checkbox formControlName="pacct">PACCT</mat-checkbox>
    <mat-checkbox style="margin-left: 40px;" formControlName="support">support license</mat-checkbox>
</div>
...
```

Comment: You could listen for the `(change)` output of the `pacct` control and `enable/disable` `support` based on that value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

```
this.userForm.get('pacct').valueChanges.pipe(
    filter((value: boolean) => !value) // continue only if 'pacct' unchecked
).subscribe((value: boolean) =>
   this.userForm.get('support').setValue(value); // update value of 'support'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure when and what you want reset. But you can use just Form.reset() method. To reset all fields of your form:

```
this.myform.reset();
```

To reset specified fields of your form:

```
this.myform.controls['FIELD_NAME'].reset();
```